# Button management in netsuite

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to create a Mark all and Unmark all button in my item list. is there any option to enable this feature to add buttons to my item list. The second is an option to copy all the marked items to the end of the list. I was trying to find a solution add a button under the items sub-list tab. 
I want to know is there any place I need to enable this Mark all/Unmark all feature.
thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

SuiteScript has an addMarkAllButtons() function that can be used like this:

```
var form = nlapiCreateForm('Custom Page Title');
var sublist = form.addSubList('listname', 'list', 'Sublist Title');
sublist.addMarkAllButtons();
```

This will display the Mark All/Unamark All buttons at the top of your sublist.

Comment: Sorry for asking again !
how do i load a default sublist and create Mark All button for that list.
I am trying to create a Mark All button for my quotaion Item sublist.

Comment: this code will help only for LIST type sub-list. can you tell me how can we use addMarkAllButtons() for Inline editor sublist. @mike-robbins

Comment: You are correct.  According to the help file, it can only be called on sublists of type LIST.

Comment: Is there any other way i can achieve this. please help me@mike-robbins